# Set max lines editable TextView - Swift/iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

The following code will set the max number of lines for a TextView.

```
textView.textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = 5;
textView.textContainer.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
```

However, when in edit mode, you can keep pressing enter beyond the max lines and type off the screen.

How can you make it so the cursor will not go to the next line if you try to type more?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
func sizeOfString (string: String, constrainedToWidth width: Double, font: UIFont) -> CGSize {
    return (string as NSString).boundingRectWithSize(CGSize(width: width, height: DBL_MAX),
        options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin,
        attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font],
        context: nil).size
}


func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    let newText = (textView.text as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: text)
    var textWidth = CGRectGetWidth(UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(textView.frame, textView.textContainerInset))
    textWidth -= 5.0 * textView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding;

    let boundingRect = sizeOfString(newText, constrainedToWidth: Double(textWidth), font: textView.font!)
    let numberOfLines = boundingRect.height / textView.font!.lineHeight;

    return numberOfLines <= 5;
}
```